# How to check the Mobile Number exist in the same user android device?

Tags: android, android-security

How can I check if the Mobile number which is entered by user on the login/signup is in the same device otherwise I don't want the user to login/signup.

In Android Q, I'm unable to access the SIM Number because of [Restriction on non-resettable device identifiers](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes#non-resettable-device-ids)

Please help on how to verify this SIM Number validation

Thanks :)

Comment: In my opinion, most of the companies just verifies the SIM with verification code. What is your reason for checking the SIM Number exist in the same user android device?

Comment: @Rifat Yeah that's a one way to check if particular mobile number is in same device.